# Extracting only tags from html text file

Tags: c#, html

I'm working on a steganography method which hides text withing html tags. 
 
 for example this tag: `<heEAd>` I have to extract every character within the tag and then 
 
analyze the case of the letter if it is capital then the *bit is set to 1 else 0*  and I also want to check the end if it sees the matching closing **/head** tag

---

here is the code :

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("url");
String Tags = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < htmlCode.Length; i++){
     if(htmlCode[i] ='<'){
      if(htmlCode[i] = '>')
       continue;
      else{
      Tags += htmlCode[i];
         }
      }

}
```

That logic is terrible but how do I use `IndexOf`  and `lastIndexOf` to get the desired
 `substring`  I tried to use that but I'm just missing something due to the lack of my knowledge about c#

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use REGEX.

I tried to do this once with `Substring` and i had much job. Latter i decided to use regex and it was easier than the first one.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=<head>).*(?=</head>)");
return regex.Matches(strInput);
```